# Trying to implement path record for Haskell binary tree search

Tags: search, haskell, binary-tree

I've been playing around with binary trees in Haskell, and I am attempting to implement a dfs variant that returns the path (composed of left and rights) from the root node to the node containing the value searched for. I think it would be best to return a `Maybe Directions` type.

Here is what has been implemented so far.

```
data Tree a = Empty | Node a (Tree a) (Tree a)
    deriving (Show, Eq)

data Direction = L | R 
    deriving (Show)
type Directions = [Direction] 

inTree :: (Eq a) => a -> Tree a -> [Direction]
inTree val (Node x l r)
    | val == x = []
    | l /= Empty = L:(inTree val l)
    | r /= Empty = R:(inTree val r)
    | otherwise =
```

but I have no idea how to have it traverse the entire tree. I feel as though I might be thinking too imperatively.

Answer (score 5):

Your idea to use `Maybe Direction` is good. I would rewrite your function as follows:

```
inTree :: (Eq a) => a -> Tree a -> Maybe [Direction]
inTree val Empty = Nothing
inTree val (Node x l r)
    | val == x = Just []
    | otherwise = (fmap (L:) (inTree val l)) <|> (fmap (R:) (inTree val r))
```

`fmap`ing a function `f` on a `Maybe` results in `Nothing` if the original value is `Nothing` and `Just (f v)` if it's `Just v`. In our case if the recursive call found the value (so it's returning a path `Just [Direction]`) we append the `Direction` we took at the current node.

The `<|>` operator comes from the [`Alternative` instance of `Maybe`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.6.0.1/docs/Control-Applicative.html#v%3a-60--124--62-). It's a left biased choice on maybes. Here we use it to pick the subtree which returned `Just [Direction]` (if there was any).

A good exercise is to modify the code so that it returns all the paths to the `x`s in the tree.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a less streamlined version similar to the style presented in the question. This might be useful for anyone on a more basic level of learning Haskell and not yet understanding the contents of the `Control.Applicative` library.

```
inTree :: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe [Direction]
inTree _ Empty = Nothing
inTree val (Node x l r)
  | val == x  = Just []
  | otherwise = case inTree val l of Just ys -> Just (L : ys)
                                     Nothing -> case inTree val r of Just ys -> Just (R : ys)
                                                                     Nothing -> Nothing
```