# Trace path of a node Binary Tree in Haskell

Tags: haskell, binary-tree

I am new to Haskell and I am trying to trace the path of a node in binary tree from the root . 
I followed this link in SO :- [Trying to implement path record for Haskell binary tree search](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21770559/trying-to-implement-path-record-for-haskell-binary-tree-search)

I modified the code for better understanding

```
inTree:: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe [Direction]
inTree x End = Nothing
inTree x (Node y l r ) = if (x == y) then  Just [] else (fmap (L:) (inTree x (Node _ l _ )) <|> (fmap (R:) (inTree x (Node _ _ r))))
```

But I got the following error when I tried to compile it :-

```
 Not in scope: ‘<|>’
    Perhaps you meant one of these:
      ‘<$>’ (imported from Prelude), ‘<*>’ (imported from Prelude)
```

Can anyone please help me fix this

Also , can anyone please explain the `3rd line` in the code above .
What is `L:` and what is `R:` ?

Edit --

After reading the comments , I have tried this using `case construct` but I have ran into the following error :-

```
inTree:: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe [Direction] 
inTree x End = Nothing
inTree x (Node y l r ) | x == y = Just [] | l\=Empty = L:(inTree x l)
```

error `Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe Direction’ with actual type ‘[Maybe Direction] -> [Maybe Direction]`

Comment: To get your hands on `<|>` you may need to add `import Control.Applicative` to the preamble of your file, just after the `module` line.

Comment: Can you explain me the third line in the code please

Comment: What is L: and R: in the above code ?

Comment: It appears that this code is probably not at the right "level" for you just yet. You should probably work your way through some more introductory material before you get to this. We *could* explain it directly (none of the concepts are particularly complicated; there are just a number of different ones stacked up on top of each other), but you'd likely end up just overwhelmed.

Comment: Big picture: we're trying to find the path inside a tree to the leftmost-outermost copy of `x`. So, we need to find a `Node y l r` where `x == y` is `True`. We're using `Maybe` to model the possibility of failure (as `x` may be nowhere), and we're trying to compute a list of directions that take us from the root to the `Node` with the copy of `x`. The `L` and `R` are directions "left" and "right" and the `:` is the "cons" function which extends a list by one element at the front. The detail of the code isn't quite right.

Comment: @dfeuer I suspect you're right. @Newbie, the `fmap` and `<|>` are doing some neat but advanced management of the search logic. It takes a while to learn that method, but you can get the same results with simpler tools. Have you seen the `case` construct yet?

Comment: How to implement the same 3rd line using `case` ?

Comment: I have tried this -`inTree:: Eq a => a -> Tree a -> Maybe [Direction]
inTree x End = Nothing
inTree x (Node y l r ) | x == y = Just [] | l\=Empty = L:(inTree x l)` . But I get this error `Couldn't match expected type ‘Maybe Direction’
                with actual type ‘[Maybe Direction] -> [Maybe Direction]`

Comment: @Newbie, you should read about `case` in a tutorial like "Learn You a Haskell". Once you've done that, you should be able to implement this without using any functions aside from `==`.